# Make a JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have strange issue, which I don't understand. I would like to make a JSON Object in JavaScript. My example code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myJson = new Object();
var data = new Object();
myJson.items = [];

data.name  = 'test';

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  data.counter = i;
  myJson.items.push(data);  
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));

});
```

Output:

```
{"items":[{"name":"test","counter":4},{"name":"test","counter":4},{"name":"test","counter":4},{"name":"test","counter":4},{"name":"test","counter":4}]}
```

Why the counter variable in JSON have always value 4 ??????

Comment: The property you're changing is always the same `data.counter`.

Answer (score 4):

You are always working on the same data object
instead try putting data object initialization in loop

```js
var myJson = new Object();

myJson.items = [];



for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var data = new Object();
  data.name  = 'test';
  data.counter = i;
  myJson.items.push(data);  
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
```

Comment: Construct objects, push them,to an array then ``JSON.stringify`` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

create a new object of `var data = new Object();` inside for loop, comment the above one, also put `data.name  = 'test';` inside for loop